# sql and UIPickerView

Tags: ios, objective-c, sql, sqlite, uipickerview

I need to develop a sql statement based on values picked on a UIPickerView. If you need a visual idea, here's a [link](http://www.corinnpope.com/?attachment_id=1044) to the screenshot (sorry not enough reputation to post pics yet) . I haven't been able to find any documentation on this and want to make sure I'm on the right track before I dig into it.

Each component (kTypeComponent, kDifficultyComponent, kDescriptionComponent) has three rows to select from (ex. kTypeComponent row1=bike, row2=run, row3=swim)

My thought would be that the sql statement would look something like this

```
    sqlite3_stmt *pickerStatement;

    //This would give back a string of the row selected (i.e bike, run, swim)
    NSInteger getTypeSelected = [pickerView selectedRowInComponent:kTypeComponent];
    NSString typeSQL = [rowOneItems objectAtIndex:getTypeSelected];

    const char *pickerSQL = "SELECT description FROM workoutTbl WHERE (type = typeSQL) AND ...
```

Is this possible to do with a sql statement? I'm only familiar with basic SQL, so I'm not sure

Would the SQL statement go in the action (button) or where I set up my NSMutableArray and open the database? Should it go into a different class?

**Edit - Solution**

In case anyone comes around with the same problem, here is the solution to it

```
    - (NSArray *)getWorkoutListwithType:(NSString *)workoutType withDifficulty:(NSString *)difficulty withLength:(NSString *)length {
NSMutableArray *workouts;
@try {
    NSFileManager *fileMgr = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
    NSString *dbPath = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] resourcePath] stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"workoutList.sqlite"];
    //        NSLog(@"Db path is %@",dbPath);
    BOOL success = [fileMgr fileExistsAtPath:dbPath];

    if (!success){
        NSLog(@"Cannot locate database file '%@'.", dbPath);
    }
    if (!(sqlite3_open([dbPath UTF8String], &db) == SQLITE_OK)) {
        NSLog(@"error with message '%s'.", sqlite3_errmsg(db));
    }

    // only alloc/init the array if the SQL database opens properly
    workouts = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    sqlite3_stmt *sqlStatement;

    // add "%%" as a wildcard so the query will say "difficulty LIKE '>30%' and match >30 MINS, >30 HOURS, etc.
    NSString *sqlString = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"SELECT description FROM workoutTbl WHERE type LIKE '%@%%' AND difficulty LIKE '%@%%' AND duration LIKE '%@%%'", workoutType, difficulty, length];
    NSLog(@"query: %@", sqlString);

    const char *sql = [sqlString UTF8String];

    if (sqlite3_prepare(db, sql, -1, &sqlStatement, NULL) != SQLITE_OK) {
        NSLog(@"%s Prepare failure '%s' (%1d)", __FUNCTION__, sqlite3_errmsg(db), sqlite3_errcode(db));
    }
    while (sqlite3_step(sqlStatement)==SQLITE_ROW) {
        [workouts addObject:[NSString stringWithUTF8String:(char *) sqlite3_column_text(sqlStatement,0)]];
    }
    sqlite3_finalize(sqlStatement);
}
@catch (NSException *exception) {
    NSLog(@"An exception occured: %@", [exception reason]);
}
@finally {
    sqlite3_close(db);
}

//    Pass back an immutable copy of the array. if the array is nil, then the database never opened and there will be an error
return [workouts copy];
```

}

Answer (score 0):

What do you mean by 'three rows to select'?  Do you mean 'three fields (columns) to select'?  If you want to specify field values, then a statement should like

```
NSString* sqlStatement = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"SELECT * FROM workoutTbl WHERE type = '%@' AND id = '%i'", typeSQL,idNumber];
```

Comment: great. This gave me the exact sql statement I needed. Do I have to convert it to a const char to use it in my prepare statement?